# limits argument in scale_x_continuous(limits), doesn't include values at extreme

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

**data**: diamonds, **histogram**: 'price'

I have a doubt regarding limits argument in scale_x_continuous, It doesn't plot extremities. I have given limits from 200 to 5125, but histogram fail to generate plot for 326 (min value)

*I chose 200 for lower limit; by 326-250/2 (min value- half of binwidth), but it included 326 when i switched lower limit to 0*

Quoting xlim description from http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/lims.html

> Observations not in this range will be dropped completely and not
> passed to any other layers. If a NA value is substituted for one of
> the limits that limit is automatically calculated.

PFB my code in R,

```
qplot(data=diamonds, x=price, color=I('black'), fill=I('#919000'), binwidth=250)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(200,5125), breaks=seq(326,5125, 500))
```

[image: Histogram of price data]

I was expecting it to include 326 as well in the plot. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: I believe this is due to binwidth. If you set it to a lower value (like 100 for example) you'll see a bar for 326.

Comment: @Haboryme is correct. Ggplot divides the data into different bins of width 250 in your example. The lower limit of the first bin that includes the data of price 326 is lower than 200 which is your lower limit for the x-axis. This causes the data to be dropped.
Therefore there are 2 solutions: Lower the limit (200) in scale_x_continuous or lower the binwidth.

Comment: the graphic doesn't correspond to your script.. (well at least for my R version)

Comment: @JeroenBoeye How much should i lower it? (how do i calculate it?)

Comment: @agenis I'm using R version 3.2.1 on platform i386, this is the plot showing on my terminal. Is this happening due to version difference?

Comment: well, just run it on fiddle, you'll see the difference: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=xybI0YUZ

Comment: @NemishKanwar If you want to be sure not to have this issue your lower limit in scale_x_continuous should be lower then the lowest value in your dataset - the binwidth. So in this case 362 - 250 = 112.

Comment: @JeroenBoeye It is 326 not 362, and i'm able to generate expected result from 125, not further. Any idea?

Comment: @NemishKanwar you are right I miss typed. The calculation I gave you should always work because it assumes the worst case scenario where the lowest value of the dataset is the upper limit of the first bin. This will rarely be the case so it is correct that you can pick a higher value. However, I don't know how to calculate the lower limit of the first bin that ggplot has created.

Comment: @agenis that was good website. Thanks!!  but i only wished to include data from 326 to 5125. With that website i'm able to plot my expected graph for (250, 5125), not further. How do i quantify '250' for the server.  It seems it's a system issue. but could you tell me how to go about it.

Comment: Considering the bin issue mentioned above. Why not simply use `limits = c(0,5125)`? By the way, first bin at 326 is shown with `limits = c(125,5125)` but not with `limits = c(126,5125)`. Strangely 125 = 250/2.

Comment: Or you could let ggplot2 figure out the lower limit using `limits = c(NA, 5125)` as it will take the bin width into account.

Comment: That worked @aosmith, but it's only a fix. What if there was an outlier in my data (lower than 326); it would have taken that as well into account. Any suggestion?